# vhdl convert subtype to type for active hdl

Tags: types, type-conversion, port, vhdl, subtype

I have a pakcgae in which I declare a bunch of subtypes and types. In Active HDL, there seems to be a problem whenever I try to make a port out of a subtype, so I'm wondering if there is a way to convert them to types instead. The following would be a subtype i'd like to convert:

subtype word_t  is std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); -- Word (definition)

Is this possible without just creating a type that is a record, or an array?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it is possible to directly create a `type` based on another `subtype`, but without the `subtype` it can be done like:

```
type word_t is array (15 downto 0) of std_logic;
```

However, creating a new `type` for the port will make use of the port cumbersome, due to the hard-type nature of VHDL.

An alternative work-around may be to make a `subtype` with the range for `word_t`, like:

```
subtype word_range_t is natural range 15 downto 0;
```

and then use that `subtype` with `std_logic_vector` in the `port` declaration, like:

```
... std_logic_vector(word_range_t);
```

The port is then still compatible with `std_logic_vector`, and the size of the word is then still easily maintainable.

Comment: Hey thank you very much, that seemed to work (second method). Now why exactly does that work?

Comment: May be a good idea to report the Active HDL issue to Aldec, so they can address the issue for future releases.  Anyway, the range by subtype is generally very useful.

Comment: I have reported it already, they have said that its a bug they will fix. thanks

Comment: Great, Aldec are usually very responsive to feedback, and that is the way to make good software.